# Simple click counter

Tags: javascript, html, dom, click, counter

I want a number starting from 10 to display in a textbox and everytime a button is clicked the number goes down by 1. How do I do this on Javascript?

Comment: What might you have tried?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/YJmPJ/

Comment: Why do *so many* people answer questions like these!

Comment: @Cthulhu - I like all the foot-thick terminology that, if the OP is really a beginner, means nothing. No explanation (however brief) of the basic concepts of a what a document is, what it means when things are joined by a period, *`var`*... Yaar! Pirates of the *Redwood Shores* mateys!

Comment: @JaredFarrish I have no idea what that meant :D. But teach a man to code... don't write his code for him, is what I meant.

Comment: @Cthulhu We're all trying to profit from the bike shed principle. :P

Comment: @Cthulhu - I just remember when I first "tried" to learn scripting. Out of my depth is one way of putting it, but I was committed. I self-learned, so I "put myself through school" with a couple of key people helping. The good ones know how to turn your face to towards the light and let you feel the heat, not shine a spotlight so confusing it hardly helps. But! I digress.

Comment: @Cthulhu - There's a really fascinating paper called *Competence in Experts: The Role of Task Characteristics*, by James Shanteau of KSU. You can download it for free, if you're interested just do a search, but the theory of experts in explaining and understanding behaviors like the one you observed I think is interesting. Signing off...

Comment: Sorry guys Im a beginner in JS and I am doing this project thats been frustrating me. I should've written what I had so you guys didnt have to assume that I'm just milking the answer from you guys. I have been learning on my own and also learning from people. Anywho, I appreciate the help and all your inputs

Comment: @JaredFarrish That paper was so far above me, I had to squint to see its outline! :)

Comment: @Cthulhu - There's a lot of terms of art. What I found spooky when I read it was how much of it paralleled our industry in those terms, such as decision, tasks, domains, expert systems, systematics, etc. See pg. 8: *They include making use of dynamic feedback, relying on decision aids, decomposing complex decision problems, and rethinking
solutions to tough situations.* As peddlers in info derived from data we construct and promote, we are de facto experts. Give it a chance; it's thick, I know. But when you get to pg. 14, *Cognitive Continuum Theory* (What?!?!), that's when it gets good.

Comment: @user1893388 - No problem, you just gotta do it. You get it one day and then it's like, you always "had" it and it's hard to think otherwise, because programming and systems analysis *fundamentally alters* the way you organize your mind. However, check out http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercises/0

Comment: @JaredFarrish One thing is for sure. I'll look at people claiming to be experts closely and try to verify the paper's claims in future. But I do agree, with the fact that once thought processes become *"automated"*, we do lose the ability to improve the basic stored functional units of thought. That is probably reason enough to revisit and rethink the fundamentals from time to time.

Comment: @Cthulhu - You're ever feeling a little light on the heftier side of your brain, just do some searches for *theory of experts*, *expert systems*, *expert networks*, and *informatics systematics*.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Looks quite interesting. Certain will :)

Answer (score 2):

Define your text field as :

```
<input type="text" name="counter" id="countField" value="10"/>
```

Then define a decreaseValue function as:

```
function decreaseValue(){
    var fieldElem = document.getElementById("countField");
    fieldElem.value = parseInt(fieldElem.value, 10) -1;
}
```

Add the above function as `onclick` function to your button, and it should be all done.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you start by making a textbox and a button:

```
<input id="mybox" type="text" value="10" />
<button id="mybutton">Decrease</button>
```

Next, you need a click handler that decrements the value in the textbox:

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener("click", function(){
    var input = document.getElementById('mybox');
    mybox.value = parseInt(mybox.value, 10) - 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have jquery included it is very simple...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var totalClicks = 10;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('INSERT THE ID OF THE BUTTON HERE').click(function() {
        totalClicks -= 1;
        $('INSERT THE NAME OF THE INPUT FIELD YOU WANT THE CONTENT HERE').val(totalClicks);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why would this need jQuery at all?

Comment: not specifically needed for this one function alone, but I'm assuming that if he's using javascript it's probably for more than just a click counter. As such, why would you not use it? write less, do more.

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6kVD9/

```
​document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;
};​​​​​
```

Notice: it is not crossbrowser, use jQuery or similar library to work with dom.

Comment: Where's the non-crossbrowsery part? You should also use the radix when using `parseInt()`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt): *While ... optional, always specify it ... to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified.*

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Why use `parseInt()` when you can just do `+input.value`?

Comment: @Derek - That's a nonsensical question. Are you wanting me to agree with you that one is better than the other? I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you specified JavaScript, I won't mention the HTML5 number input.... ooops. ;)

Anywho, JavaScript:

```
function counter(id){
input = document.getElemenyById(id); // the id of the element with the decreasing value

input.value = input.value - 1; //or input.value-- I guess
}
```

In HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="id" value="10" /><!-- Field containing the value that is changed -->
<input type="button" name="counter" onclick="counter('id');" value="Clicky!" /> <!-- Button that changes the value when clicked -->
```